# How is the deployment process handled in scrum methodology?

Tags: deployment, scrum

We are developing a complex system using scrum methodology with 1 week sprints and a team of 6 developers.

We continuously update the source code on every developer machine when the changes are tested and integrated on the development branches, and the developers daily integrate the changes to a test common server.

But the production system is critical enough for any issue or downtime to cause much $ lost, and the deployment process is slow, hard and delicate. Even if the system changes are tested and even deployed to a test server, sometimes problems arise when we try to publish the whole week progress as a lot. Thus, we have chose to have a previous deployment process which happens after all the week development is completed and deployed to the test server. We run full feature tests on the whole week changes on the test server, then publish the week work lot to a preproduction server, then sometimes everything goes fine but sometimes some new problems arise on the deployment process or the published changes, then we plan the highly delicate production process and execute it on the next night we can, avoiding any downtime for the customer work.

Now, we are having discussions with the customer since he defends this is not scrum because he isn't gettint the sprint result on the scrum day, but three days later. But obviously we can't start the pre-release and release process until the sprint completes totally - so, next day - and then the system complexity and criticality forces us to secure the deployment process to the top, and the customer production usage requires also some special operation scheduling.

Are we working against the scrum guidelines? Where is the deployment process on the scrum methodology? Is scrum appropiate for this project?

Answer (score 2):

> the deployment process is slow, hard and delicate.

When a deployment process is hard, it tends to mean organisations deploy less frequently. If they deploy less often then releases become bigger, more difficult and more critical. This tends to mean that there is even more reluctance to release.

This negative cycle works against Agile as it means organisations struggle to respond to change.

The best thing you can do is try and break out of this cycle by improving the release process. This may be difficult and consume time and resources, but the benefits are significant.

If you can automate your releases then you tend to reduce the risk. With the risk lowered then releasing more frequently becomes possible. Frequent releases means that the size of releases is reduced and you can quickly fix bugs if necessary.

Frequent releases also make the customer happier as they get more opportunities to provide feedback. The more feedback they give, the sooner the product will be what they want.

Perhaps a good place to start would be to automate the releases you currently make to the common test server. Once you have been doing this for a while you should have the confidence to use the same process on production.

Answer (score 0):

Barnaby has the ideal answer. In the meantime, one possibility is to have a repeating story each sprint to release the approved stories from the previous sprint. Per the [Scrum Guide](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html), a team only delivers "a potentially releasable Increment of (a) 'Done' product at the end of each Sprint." The key word is "potentially." In addition to the problem you face, I have been in companies that only released once a quarter because that is what the customers wanted. If your customer wants a release every sprint, great, but nothing in the guide requires that to happen in the same sprint the stories are accepted in.

To clarify based on the comment, let's assume a team is using a traditional Dev-Test-Stage-Production architecture. The customer would review the changes in Stage (during the Demonstration Ceremony if not before). Accepted stories go into the release, which moves to Prod as part of the recurring "Release" story in the next sprint.

Comment: Huhmmm... but then, the feedback for the released increment can't be included into the scrum meeting at the end of this sprint because the customer can't test the results, is that scrum-valid?